# Approve post and send the password

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to add my password reset function code
the code what it does is that when the mail arrives to the user, click on Confirm and the post is published. (before it was pending)

I just want to click on a link and publish the post and send it to the link to reset the password (to generate it, any other idea is welcome)

Thank you!!

```
// create an url vor verify link with some variables: key, post id, and email
 $url = add_query_arg( 
array(
'email'=>$author->user_email,
'approve'=>$post->ID),
site_url()
 );

 $content = '<table class="body_bg" style="max-width: 600px; border-radius: 5px;" role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


Tu cuenta ha sido activada.
  Completa tu perfil en:

 <a href="' . $url . '"  target="_blank" class="button">Confirmar</a>
</br>
Te deseamos un buen día!
</td>';

 $check = md5( $author->user_email . $post->ID  );
 update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_approve_key', $check);
```

maybe joining with this code?

```
 function reset_password1($user, $new_pass) {
        do_action('password_reset', $user, $new_pass);
        wp_set_password($new_pass, $user->ID);

        wp_password_change_notification($user); //i dont want other email more...
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand why resetting the password would publish a post. Is this the user's first password, i.e. it's really an email address confirmation, and the user did not have a password before? What is the post here and where did it come from? Did the user write it as part of the sign up process?

Comment: Yes this is correct. The user registers answering questions that generate a post.
Therefore, this doesn`t have a password. If he confirms the post, he allows me to confirm his mail.
Any suggestions?